# Can I have sex with an unknown person if my husband has been abroad for around five years?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, husband-wife

My husband has been abroad for about the last five years and I am very thirsty for sex, but he is not here.  Can I have sex with another person?

Comment: Nope, why don't you ask for a divorce instead and marry someone else?

Comment: I'll rephrase your question for you: Is zina haram if my husband is abroad for five years? do you still need an answer for that? If not than you might need to solve this issue with your husband, either you live together or you need to see each other more often, or you need to separate (divorce) and get married to somebody who could fullfill your desires and stay with you. As you see this isn't a question which is focused enough to answer here (see [ask]).

Answer (score 0):

You have good grounds for divorce, if there is no objection from your husband.  Then you could remarry and commence relations with someone new.  The tradition of punishment for adultery when married was public execution.  The sin is rated only slightly lower than murder.  These matters are found within the Qur'an, and common Islamic texts.

Comment: The *reason* of committing adultery dictates its punishment. Sometimes there is no punishment. See [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36671/legal-system-does-sharia-command-courts-of-appeal/36895#36895). For this case I'm *guessing* there is a punishment but surely not the one you mentioned. Everyone can use Qur'an but if they are to draw conclusions it has to be in conformance to Qur'an itself. If there is a dilemma then they must seek guidance from a religious authority otherwise you would be making strict, radical conclusions.