# According to scholars who view transgenderism as haram, what should a post-operative transsexual do?

Tags: medical, transgender

There's a difference of opinion as to whether being transgender is haram; see my answer [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/33460/17163).  An example fatwa which says it's haram is:

> We know, therefore, that these operations are prohibited and that no one from among the scholars whose opinion is considered permits them, save with the exception mentioned in the council's response. --  [Dr. Hatem al-Haj](http://www.drhatemalhaj.com/), [Assembly of Muslim Jurists of America](http://www.amjaonline.org/en/) (AMJA) ([Fatwa 22813](http://www.amjaonline.org/fatwa-22813/info), 2007)

Some [transgender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transgender) people undergo [sex reassignment surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_reassignment_surgery), where the reproductive organs of an individual are surgically altered to be (more) consistent with their gender.  It's not considered a reversible operation, e.g., vaginoplasty includes amputation of the penis and testes.

Suppose a post-operative transsexual accepts such fatawa and thinks they've made a mistake and wants to correct it.  I'm wondering how they would go about making amends.

**Question**: According to scholars who view transgenderism as haram, what should a post-operative transsexual do?

Ordinarily, by the time they get to the point of surgery, transgender individuals will have established themselves as their identified gender, and have probably undergone many other medical procedures.  They do this because they genuinely believe they are of the gender they identify with.

It may be that these scholars suggest to reverse all this to the greatest possible extent.  Or perhaps the impracticality and reduction in quality of life makes it recommended to stick with the identified gender.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing an answer to the effect of "this is considered among the medical questions which should not be answered by Islamic scholars" backed up with evidence (and not just opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheikh [Assim Al Hakeem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assim_al-Hakeem) addressed this topic, which is available in [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUcrZxIkhHY).  His stance is that a post-operative transsexual woman should endeavor to act like a man, and they should theoretically get "the surgery" reversed (presumably referring to [gender reassignment surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_reassignment_surgery)) although he acknowledged it's impracticality.

---

Here's my transcript of the relevant part of the YouTube video:

> But a person who's a normal man, or a normal woman, and just wanting to change to the opposite gender, this is totally prohibited and unaccepted, so what would this woman (so-called, quote unquote) do because she's now a woman (originally her name was John, but now she's Jeanette, so what can we do with her?).  After she accepts Islam, we tell her that [...], Allah forgives all of your previous sins so now you are a clean book, and your sheet is white; there's not a stain on it.  But, you are still John.  You're still a man.  Even if you underwent this hormonal, uh.., transformation, and **even if you did the surgery, you're still considered to be a man.  Reverse it, if you can (the surgery, I don't think it can be reversed), but at least you have to look like a man, act like a man, and be with men.**

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you killed someone...can you bring that person back to life?! No. Can you repent? Yes. Can you repent wholeheartedly? Yes. What good would that do?

> *قُلْ يَا عِبَادِيَ الَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلَىٰ أَنفُسِهِمْ لَا تَقْنَطُوا مِن رَّحْمَةِ اللَّهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ
>   جَمِيعًا ۚ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ*
>
> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by
>   sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah
>   forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the
>   Merciful."
>
> <sub>[Zumar : 53](https://quran.com/39/53)</sub>

---

> *إِلَّا مَن تَابَ وَآمَنَ وَعَمِلَ عَمَلًا صَالِحًا فَأُولَٰئِكَ يُبَدِّلُ اللَّهُ سَيِّئَاتِهِمْ حَسَنَاتٍ ۗ وَكَانَ اللَّهُ غَفُورًا
>   رَّحِيمًا*
>
> For them Allah will **replace** their evil deeds with good. And ever is
>   Allah Forgiving and Merciful.
>
> <sub>[Furqan : 70](https://quran.com/25/70)</sub>

---

Also:

- Try do good more and more and more in the name of Allah.
- If this person was never informed that it's a sin or never thought of it being a sin, then *perhaps* they won't be punished to the same level of one who knows or [not punished at all](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36671/legal-system-does-sharia-command-courts-of-appeal/36895#36895).

Answer (score -1):

In the name of Allah, the most gracious, the most merciful.

The first thing you need to know is that ALLAH the Exalted is the God of Jesus and his mother, Mary and all the prophets like Moses, Abraham, Jacob, David etc... Peace be upon them all, ALLAH the Merciful is loving, he will never punish an innocent soul or a soul that repents sincerely.

You know in your mind that you are a woman regardless of the genitals because genitals don't determine who you are, Never! If a man loses his genitals in an accident, is he considered a woman? Or is he considered a man? Think about it.

You know from the moment you can remember you knew you were normal, you knew you were a woman but the ignorance around us has shamed us into thinking we are abnormal, worthless, sick in the head and so on and on...

There are no punishment prescribed in the Qur'an nor the Hadiths (the latter I don't believe in), many scholars have said that the nature of hadiths is very sensitive and many words are misinterpreted and makes many things haraam (Forbidden).

The Wonderful Qur'an recognizes that there are some people who are both male and female, whether physically, psychologically or both, there aren't any specifications, so it applies to us as we are physically undoubtedly male and psychologically without question, female.

Verses 49 to 50 of the 42nd Chapter of the glorious Qur'an states " To Allah belongs the dominion of the heavens and the earth; He creates what he wills. He gives to whom He wills female [children], and He gives to whom He wills males, Or He makes them [both] males and females, and He renders whom He wills barren. Indeed, He is Knowing and Competent.

- Saheeh international translation.

The verses in fact describe varieties of gender and sexuality, ALLAH the Exalted, clearly says "He makes them BOTH male and female" the verse can refer to physical, psychological or both forms of ambiguity.

Comment: While I don't want to discourage you from posting, the question is *According to scholars who view transgenderism as haram, what should a post-operative transsexual do?* and this answer doesn't answer that question.  (Whether or not those scholars' opinions are valid is not part of the question.)